# Covariance matrix of uniform distribution over the Sierpinski triangle

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, covariance, fractals, fractal-analysis

Let $(X_1, X_2)$ be uniform over the unit Sierpinski triangle (represented in Cartesian coordinates). What is its covariance matrix?

This is a question I saw in a [jobs ad](https://slatestarcodex.com/blog_images/sierpinski_med_res.png). I would love some leads on solving it.

Comment: Certainly, the covariance must be zero, due to the relationship between covariance and correlation and the symmetry of the standard Sierpinski triangle.

Comment: @MarkMcClure any idea how one could show this "the long way around"? I'm very interested in probabilistic reasoning over fractal distributions!

Comment: Yeah - numerical estimations are easy but theoretical computations involve a bit more work. Are you sure the question asks for the full covariance matrix? That essentially means you need to compute the $X$ and $Y$ variances. That can be done, but is not totally easy.

Comment: This isn't homework, FWIW. I'd love to know how to do the variance of each distribution. I figure I should start with an iterative refinement and see if it converges?

Comment: You know how to express the variances as integrals with respect to the uniform distribution? If so, then an approach similar to the one I outline in my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294046) should work. I believe that both variances are $1/18$.

Comment: Is this triangle bounded by the triangle with vertices $(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1)$?  It's unclear to me.

Comment: @BrianTung Fair question - which is another reason that it would be great to see the original question quoted in full. Having said that, I do think that most references to the Sierpinski triangle would construct it as an equilateral triangle with base on the unit interval. That's certainly how I took it when doing my computations.

Comment: Find the original question [here](https://slatestarcodex.com/blog_images/sierpinski_med_res.png). It's less than clear, but to me it looks like equilateral triangle with unit vertices (like @MarkMcClure said).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this answer, I will interpret the "unit Sierpinski triangle $S$" as being the one with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$.  If you want to use the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$ instead (i.e. beginning with an equilateral triangle) then a very similar method should work.

I will also interpret the "uniformity" condition on the probability measure $\mu$ on $S$ as meaning that the contraction of $S$ to each of its subtriangles of level 1, $S_{00}$, $S_{01}$, and $S_{10}$, respects measure except that it multiplies it by $\frac{1}{3}$.

Now, this will imply that for any measurable and $L^1$ function $f : S \to \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$ \int_{S_{00}} f(x,y) d\mu = \frac{1}{3} \int_S f \left(\frac{1}{2}x, \frac{1}{2}y \right) d\mu; \\
\int_{S_{01}} f(x,y) d\mu = \frac{1}{3} \int_S f \left(\frac{1}{2} x, \frac{1}{2}y + \frac{1}{2} \right); \\
\int_{S_{10}} f(x,y) d\mu = \frac{1}{3} \int_S f \left(\frac{1}{2} x + \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} y \right).$$
The reason: it must hold for any characteristic function of a set by the uniformity condition; then, by linearity it must hold for simple functions; then, the definitions of Lebesgue integrals for nonnegative functions and for $L^1$ functions will extend the equations to all $L^1$ functions.

We can also show that the function $x : S \to \mathbb{R}$ must be measurable: for any dyadic rational $q$, $x^{-1}([q, \infty)) = \{ (x, y) \in S \mid x \ge q \}$ is a finite union of subtriangles of $S$ and therefore measurable.  However, the intervals $[q, \infty)$ with $q$ a dyadic rational generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.  Similarly, the function $y : S \to \mathbb{R}$ must be measurable.  And then, since both $x$ and $y$ are bounded functions on $S$ and $\mu$ is a finite measure, it follows that they are also in $L^1(\mu)$.

Using this, we can now calculate:
$$E(x) = \int_S x\,d\mu = \int_{S_{00}} x\,d\mu + \int_{S_{01}} x\,d\mu + \int_{S_{10}} x\,d\mu = \\
\frac{1}{3} \int_S \frac{1}{2}x\,d\mu + \frac{1}{3} \int_S \frac{1}{2}x\,du + \frac{1}{3} \int_S \left( \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2} \right) d\mu = \\
\frac{1}{2} \int_S x\,d\mu + \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{2} E(x) + \frac{1}{6}.$$
It follows that $E(x) = \frac{1}{3}$.  Very similarly, $E(y) = \frac{1}{3}$.

The calculation of $E(x^2), E(xy), E(y^2)$ will be very similar (using the previous results for $E(x)$ and $E(y)$ in intermediate steps).

Comment: I concur with this and get$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 2/27 & -1/27 \\ -1/27 & 2/27 \\ \end{array}\right)$$ for the final covariance matrix. The [original ad](https://slatestarcodex.com/blog_images/sierpinski_med_res.png) did use an equilateral triangle however.

Comment: Actually, I guess since the equilateral Sierpinski triangle is the image of this "binary representation" Sierpinski triangle under a linear transformation, you wouldn't need to restart the calculations from scratch.  If the linear transformation is $P$, then the covariance matrix should transform as $\Omega' = P^T \Omega P$.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @MarkMcClure in the comments (and the wonderful [linked answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294046/calculate-moment-of-inertia-of-koch-snowflake)), both the numerical and exact answer of points sampled from the Sierpinski triangle seems to be $(1/18) \mathbf{I}_2$ when you consider the points as N-dimensional samples $X=(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_N)^T$. If however, you consider the *transpose* of that $Y = X^T$ you get the answer below. While not correct, it was fun to work through and I'll leave it up as long as people still think it has some value.

### Original Answer

Not directly an answer, but there are simple direct insights you can make into the problem by sampling. First, sample a few thousand points using the [chaos game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_game). [image]

Compute the covariance matrix $C = \textrm{Cov}(X_1,X_2)$ and then the eigenvectors, $Cv = \lambda v$. You'll quickly find that the largest eigenvalue *dominates* all of the rest. In this sample $\lambda_1 / \lambda_2 \approx 10^{15}$. Sort $C$ by this eigenvector $v_1$ and you get a beautiful and smooth matrix:

[image]

For the final visual, color the points by this $v_1$

[image]

All of this suggests that the answer to the original question has a nice closed form.

Comment: Hmm... shouldn't the covariance matrix be 2 by 2?

Comment: @MarkMcClure it's possible that there is a nomenclature error on my part here. I'm using this definition https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html where N points in d dimensions gives me an NxN matrix. Was the question about the transpose giving a dxd matrix?

Comment: @MarkMcClure taking the 2x2 matrix gives ~ $0.05 * \mathbf{I}$

Comment: That sounds right - I computed it to be $I/18$ using the techniques on the comments. If you modifiy, I'll upvote. :)

Comment: The definition you pointed to in the numpy documentation looks good, by the way. In this situation, we have $N=2$.

Comment: @MarkMcClure turns out, I totally misread the problem as stated in the prior comment. I like the pictures for the _other_ problem I worked on so I thought I'd leave it up. I've brought attention to your comment/answer at the top and thanks for showing me the Strichartz paper (it's really interesting!).