# What is the integral of $e^{a\cdot x+b\cdot y}$ evaluated _under_ the Koch Curve

Tags: integration, fractional-calculus

Grew out of frustration about *this* question; just replace "over" by "under":

- [What is the integral of $e^{a\cdot x+b\cdot y}$ evaluated over the Koch Curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1255970/what-is-the-integral-of-ea-cdot-xb-cdot-y-evaluated-over-the-koch-curve)

What is
$$
 \iint_{K} e^{a \cdot x + b \cdot y} \,dx\,dy
$$
integrated over the area between between the x-axis and the Koch curve.
Assume that the Koch curve is between $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$. It is common
integration that is requested for, or at least an approximation to it.
No fancy "measure" stories, just a method to calculate the integral, i.e.
an algorithm or a series expansion (because it's reasonable to assume  that there is no closed form).
A real number (approximation) for the case that $a=b=1$ would be nice, so that different outcomes can be compared.

I've been thinking about the following method:

1. Calculate the integral for an arbitrary triangle with
   vertex coordinates $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3)$
2. Find the vertices of all triangles in a finite iterand of the Koch curve
3. Find the integral for this finite interand, which is the sum of known integrals
   over triangles
4. Let the number of triangles grow to infinity and determine the limit

All much in the way as it is as done **[here](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch-kromme)**

But first we must calculate the exponent for an arbitrary triangle. The key mechanism
for doing this is described in:

- [Example of a Problem Made Easier with Skew Coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837245/example-of-a-problem-made-easier-with-skew-coordinates/1086013#1086013)

With this theory:
$$
\iint_{K} e^{a \cdot x+ b \cdot y} \,dx\,dy =\\ \lim_{\#\Delta\to\infty} \sum_\Delta
O_\Delta \int_0^1 \left[ \int_0^{1-\xi} e^{a \left[x_1 + (x_2-x_1)\xi + (x_3-x_1)\eta\right]
+ b \left[y_1 + (y_2-y_1)\xi + (y_3-y_1)\eta \right]}\;d\eta\right]d\xi
$$
With $O_\Delta = (x_2-x_1)(y_3-y_1)-(x_3-y_1)(y_2-y_1)$ twice the area of the triangle
$\Delta$.
The integrals can be computed exactly, for one triangle. You can do it
by hand or invoke a computer algebra system. The result is:
$$
\left[ {e^{a{\it x_2}+b{\it y_2}}}\,a{\it x_1}+{e^{a{\it x_2}+b{
\it y_2}}}\,b{\it y_1}-{e^{a{\it x_2}+b{\it y_2}}}\,a{\it x_3}-{
e^{a{\it x_2}+b{\it y_2}}}\,b{\it y_3}+{e^{a{\it x_3}+b{\it y_3}}
}\,a{\it x_2}-{e^{a{\it x_3}+b{\it y_3}}}\,a{\it x_1}\\+{e^{a{\it x_3}+
b{\it y_3}}}\,b{\it y_2}-{e^{a{\it x_3}+b{\it y_3}}}\,b{\it y_1}-{e
^{a{\it x_1}+b{\it y_1}}}\,a{\it x_2}+{e^{a{\it x_1}+b{\it y_1}}}\,a{
\it x_3}-{e^{a{\it x_1}+b{\it y_1}}}\,b{\it y_2}+{e^{a{\it x_1}+b
{\it y_1}}}\,b{\it y_3} \right]\\ / \left[
\left( -a{\it x_3}+a{\it x_1}-b{\it y_3}+
b{\it y_1} \right)  \left( a{\it x_2}-a{\it x_3}+b{\it y_2}-b{
\it y_3} \right)  \left( -a{\it x_2}+a{\it x_1}-b{\it y_2}+b{
\it y_1} \right) \right]
$$
But after this first step I'm stuck, because it seems to become too prohibiting
to proceed in this way. Any good ideas to make things more amenable and work towards completing the steps (2), (3) and (4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the proposed integration over the area under the Koch curve, it's easier
to employ Green's theorem and integrate over the x-axis and then backwards over the
Koch curve (i.e. in counterclockwise order):
$$
\iint \left[ \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} \right] \,dx\,dy =
\oint \left[ P\,dx + Q\,dy \right]
$$
There are several possible choices for $P(x,y)$ and $Q(x,y)$ but this one will be ours:
$$
P(x,y) = -\frac{e^{a \cdot x + b \cdot y}}{b} \quad ; \quad Q(x,y) = 0
$$
Giving:
$$
\iint_K e^{a \cdot x + b \cdot y} \,dx\,dy = - \frac{1}{b} \oint_K e^{a \cdot x + b \cdot y}\,dx =
- \frac{1}{b}\int_0^1 e^{a \cdot x + 0}\,dx - \frac{1}{b} \int_K e^{a \cdot x +  b \cdot y}\,dx
$$
Where the last integral is over the Koch curve from the right $(1,0)$ to the left $(0,0)$. So:
$$
\iint_K e^{a \cdot x + b \cdot y} \,dx\,dy =
\left(1-e^a\right)/(ab) + \frac{1}{b}\int_K e^{a \cdot x +  b \cdot y}\,dx
$$
If we reverse the integration over the Koch curve from the left $(0,0)$ to the right $(1,0)$.
[image]

The method as proposed in the question is thus replaced by the following:

1. Calculate the integral for an arbitrary line segment with
   vertex coordinates $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$
2. Find the vertices of all line segments in a finite iterand of the Koch curve
3. Find the integral for this finite interand, which is the sum of known integrals
   over line segments
4. Let the number of line segments grow to infinity; determine the limit eventually
   (and/or approximately)

First we must calculate the exponent for an arbitrary line segment $S$.
Let
$\,x = x_1 + (x_2-x_1)t\,$ and $\,y = y_1 + (y_2-y_1)t$ , then:
$$
\int_{S} e^{a \cdot x+ b \cdot y}\, dx =
\int_0^1 e^{a \left[x_1 + (x_2-x_1)t \right] 
+ b \left[y_1 + (y_2-y_1)t \right]}\;(x_2-x_1)\,dt =\\
(x_2-x_1)\frac{e^{a x_2 + b y_2}-e^{a x_1 + b y_1}}{(a x_2 + b y_2)-(a x_1 + b y_1)}
$$
The following (Pascal) program defines finite iterands of a Koch curve,
recursively. Arbitrary values of $a$ and $b$ can be substituted in the
test procedure eventually. Several tests are built in to ensure that
the program works correctly. The variable `sum` is used to sum up for
the requested `Zach` integral, but another variable `som` is used to sum up for
the `Area` under the Koch curve, which is exactly known for each iterand.
The outcome of the integral for one triangle, as mentioned in the question,
can be used for verifying the current integration procedure for the first
interand `Koch(1,a,b,1)`.

```
program Zachter;

type
  vertex = record
    x,y : double;
  end;
  segment = array[1..2] of vertex;
  triangle = array[1..3] of vertex;
var
  phi,p,q,sum,som : double;

function opp(S : segment; a,b : double) : double;
var
  x_1,x_2, y_1,y_2, f : double;
begin
  x_1 := S1.x; x_2 := S[2].x;
  y_1 := S1.y; y_2 := S[2].y;
  f := (y_1+y_2)/2;
  opp := f*(x_2-x_1);
end;

function lijn(S : segment; a,b : double) : double;
var
  x_1,x_2, y_1,y_2, f : double;
begin
  x_1 := S1.x; x_2 := S[2].x;
  y_1 := S1.y; y_2 := S[2].y;
  f := (exp(a*x_2+b*y_2)-exp(a*x_1+b*y_1))
     / ((a*x_2+b*y_2)-(a*x_1+b*y_1));
  lijn := f*(x_2-x_1)/b;
end;

procedure voorts(len : double; a,b : double);
var
  S : segment;
begin
  S1.x := p; S1.y := q;
  p := p+cos(phi)*len;
  q := q+sin(phi)*len;
  S[2].x := p; S[2].y := q;
  sum := sum + lijn(S,a,b);
  som := som + opp(S,a,b);
end;

procedure turnleft(angle : integer);
begin
  phi := phi+angle*Pi/180;
end;

procedure turnright(angle : integer);
begin
  phi := phi-angle*Pi/180;
end;

procedure Koch(len,a,b: Double; count: Integer);
begin
  If count = 0 then
    voorts(len,a,b)
  else begin
    Koch(len/3,a,b, count-1);
    turnleft(60);
    Koch(len/3,a,b, count-1);
    turnright(120);
    Koch(len/3,a,b, count-1);
    turnleft(60);
    Koch(len/3,a,b, count-1);
  end;
end;

function kernel(D : triangle; a,b : double) : double;
var
  x_1,x_2,x_3, y_1,y_2,y_3, f : double;
begin
  x_1 := D1.x; x_2 := D[2].x; x_3 := D[3].x;
  y_1 := D1.y; y_2 := D[2].y; y_3 := D[3].y;
  f := -(exp(a*x_2+b*y_2)*a*x_1+exp(a*x_2+b*y_2)*b*y_1-exp(a*x_2+b*y_2)
     *a*x_3-exp(a*x_2+b*y_2)*b*y_3+exp(a*x_3+b*y_3)*a*x_2-exp(a*x_3+b*y_3)
     *a*x_1+exp(a*x_3+b*y_3)*b*y_2-exp(a*x_3+b*y_3)*b*y_1-exp(a*x_1+b*y_1)
     *a*x_2+exp(a*x_1+b*y_1)*a*x_3-exp(a*x_1+b*y_1)*b*y_2+exp(a*x_1+b*y_1)
     *b*y_3)/(-a*x_3+a*x_1-b*y_3+b*y_1)/(a*x_2-a*x_3+b*y_2-b*y_3)
     /(-a*x_2+a*x_1-b*y_2+b*y_1);
  kernel := f*((x_2-x_1)(y_3-y_1)-(x_3-x_1)(y_2-y_1));
end;

procedure test(a,b : double);
var
  k : integer;
  f,t : double;
  D : triangle;
begin
  f := 4/9; t := 1;
  for k := 0 to 12 do
  begin
    p := 0; q := 0; phi := 0;
    som := 0;
    sum := (1-exp(a))/(a*b);
    Koch(1,a,b,k);
  { http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch-kromme }
    Writeln('Area =',som,' =',(1-t)*9/5*sqrt(3)/36);
    if k=1 then
    begin
      Write('Zach =',sum,'= ');
      D1.x := 1/3; D1.y := 0; 
      D[2].x := 2/3; D[2].y := 0; 
      D[3].x := 1/2; D[3].y := sqrt(3)/6;
      Writeln(kernel(D,a,b));
    end else Writeln('Zach =',sum);
    t := t*f;
  end;
end;

begin
  test(2,3);
end.
```

Output for $a=2$ and $b=3$ , thirteen interations:

```
Area = 0.00000000000000E+0000 = 0.00000000000000E+0000
Zach = 0.00000000000000E+0000
Area = 4.81125224324688E-0002 = 4.81125224324688E-0002
Zach = 1.79819984312336E-0001=  1.79819984312336E-0001
Area = 6.94958657357883E-0002 = 6.94958657357883E-0002
Zach = 2.67676463467801E-0001
Area = 7.89995738705970E-0002 = 7.89995738705969E-0002
Zach = 3.07390573739620E-0001
Area = 8.32234441527343E-0002 = 8.32234441527341E-0002
Zach = 3.25080441215073E-0001
Area = 8.51007198336841E-0002 = 8.51007198336840E-0002
Zach = 3.32944604962222E-0001
Area = 8.59350645807717E-0002 = 8.59350645807728E-0002
Zach = 3.36439888372271E-0001
Area = 8.63058844683464E-0002 = 8.63058844683678E-0002
Zach = 3.37993352588789E-0001
Area = 8.64706933071906E-0002 = 8.64706933072990E-0002
Zach = 3.38683781372148E-0001
Area = 8.65439416795354E-0002 = 8.65439416801572E-0002
Zach = 3.38990638617374E-0001
Area = 8.65764965093825E-0002 = 8.65764965125387E-0002
Zach = 3.39127019600374E-0001
Area = 8.65909653108997E-0002 = 8.65909653269305E-0002
Zach = 3.39187633284637E-0001
Area = 8.65973958352309E-0002 = 8.65973959111046E-0002
Zach = 3.39214572284906E-0001
```

The outcome is expected to converge, but not very fast,
and there is quite some loss of precision, as is seen
with the Area outputs.